# multiprocessing python and variables

Tags: queue, python-multiprocessing

i tried to check thread safe append() ? I'm not sure it's safe  and write this.
I usually use threading and there I have a lot of code where I found that append() is not safe, although maybe I made a mistake there somewhere. I decided to look at the work of multiprocessing, but the first thing I encountered was return
_winapi.DuplicateHandle(
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
I use windows

1. how to solve this problem
   , but when I started running this code on linux, the program was stoped before reaching the for loop after queue.join(). I tried to be used
   queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue() , but it did not bring results like other combinations, but everything does not work
2. how to run the code correctly so that it works
3. then please look at the variable "list_dict" it is filled in the queue but for some reason it is empty after the queue is running and the for loop iterates through an empty list, I tried to use global but it didn't help , ,
4. in another code there is dict0[some_key] = func1(request(....)) and dict1[some_key].append[func2(request(....))] I'm not sure that append() is thread safe - please comment.

code

```
import copy
import random
import threading
import time
from random import randint
import multiprocessing

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
list_dict = []

def rand(key):
    if key == 'a':
        return random.randint(0, 5)
    else:
        return random.randint(6, 9)

def qwer(app):
    def run1(queue1, list_dict1):
        while True:
            [data1] = queue1.get()
            key = [key for key in data1][0]
            data1[key].append(rand(key))
            list_dict1.append(data1)
            print(list_dict1)

    for i in range(0, 2):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run1, args=(queue, list_dict), daemon=True)
        process_name = process.name
        app.list_process1.append(process)
        app.list_process_names1.append(process_name)
        process.start()
    len1 = 20
    list_data = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            list_data.append({'a': []})
        else:
            list_data.append({'b': []})
    for i1 in range(0, len1):
        i1 = i1 % 10
        data = list_data[i1]
        data2 = copy.deepcopy(data)
        queue.put([data2])
    queue.join()
    for di in list_dict:
        key = [key for key in di][0]
        if key == 'a':

            if di['a'][0] not in range(0, 6):
                print(di, False)
        else:
            if di['b'][0] not in range(6, 10):
                print(di, False)
    return list_dict
```

Comment: This program doesn't actually DO anything.  You create an empty Queue and an empty list and then exit.  You never call any of the functions.  Please fix it, and it would be much better if you asked just ONE question.

Comment: do you try to start it ?  quque is not empty ! I'm sure you're mistaken

Comment: Yes, I tried to start it and nothing happened.  There are only 2 executable statements.  Neither of the functions is ever called.  Perhaps the listing you posted is not the complete code of your program.

Comment: have you called a function  qwer(app)  with any value app ?

Comment: No, I haven't.  I don't want to be rude, but why do you expect me (or the SO community in general) to guess how to modify your program in order to reproduce your problem?  If all it takes is adding a simple function call, why don't you modify the question so we can both run the same program?